# How do you check if a given sentence is avoiding a certain letter in java?

Tags: java, boolean

I have been trying to figure out how to see if a given sentence is a lipogram avoiding the letter E. I have gotten to the point where I put in the true/false statements, but it is only outputting "This sentence is not a Lipogram avoiding the letter e. " every time, whether the input contains e or not. What am I doing wrong?

```
boolean avoidsE = false, hasE = true, avoidsS = false, containsS = true;

for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
{
  if (sentence.charAt(i) == 'e')
  hasE = true;
  else
  avoidsE = false;
}

if (hasE = true)
System.out.println("This sentence is not a Lipogram avoiding the letter e. ");
else if (avoidsE = false)
System.out.println("This sentence is a Lipogram avoiding the letter e! ");
```

Comment: You are now assigning `true` into the variable `hasE`, which returns true. You want to use a [comparison](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

Comment: `if (hasE = true)` ==> Should just be `if (hasE)` or `if (hasE == true)`

Answer (score 2):

```
if (hasE == true) // "=" is to assign, you want to use "==" here to check  
    System.out.println("This sentence is not a Lipogram avoiding the letter e. "); 
else if (avoidsE == false) //same here   
    System.out.println("This sentence is a Lipogram avoiding the letter e! ");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare something you should use double equals ==

For search if an character is in the string you can use **contains** method and to check if letter is not contained in the string you can use **indexOf**. It would be something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sentence = "This is your sentence";

    if(sentence.contains("e")){
        System.out.println("This sentence is not a Lipogram avoiding the letter e. ");
    }
    else if("e".indexOf(sentence) < 0){
        System.out.println("This sentence is a Lipogram avoiding the letter e!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel here.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(hasChar("asdfe", 'e'));
        System.out.println(hasChar("asdfghij", 'e'));
    }

    static boolean hasChar(String str, char c) {
        return str.chars().anyMatch(x -> x == c);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

Comment: Isn't that basically `str.contains(c)`?

Comment: ya. i was just generally curious if java 8 had a string stream which would be applicable for more advanced filtering.

Comment: It does, but no need to confuse the poster, which just has a simple typo.

Comment: @newToScala funny starting comment, when you're reinventing the wheel yourself